# Laravel Scheduled Job using updateOrCreate method

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make a scheduled job that will take data from a table in one database and insert it into a table on another database. The job will run every minute, so I need to check for duplicates and insert only the new data.
This is what I have in my Job:

```
 $db_maintenance_old = DB::connection('maintenance_old');
        $getMaintenanceMachines = $db_maintenance_old->table('machines')->get();
        foreach ($getMaintenanceMachines as $key => $value) {
            MaintenanceMachine::updateOrCreate([
                'machine_name' => $value->Code,
                'external_id' => $value->MachnineID,
            ],[
                'machine_name' => $value->Code,
                'external_id' => $value->MachnineID,
                'machine_status' => 1,
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ]);
        }
```

With *php artisan schedule:run* I get this error:
BadMethodCallException  : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrCreate()

I think I am using the updateOrCreate Method right, or maybe not. I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: that method only exists for Eloquent Builder, has to be used with Models not query builder directly

Comment: So in my case, the problem is in the way I am getting the data from the database? $getMaintenanceMachines = $db_maintenance_old->table('machines')->get();

Comment: if you are not going to use Eloquent you do have access to `updateOrInsert` with Query Builder ... it may be a good idea to look into the concept of "upserts" depending on the database you are using though so you can bulk these

Comment: btw do you really need to check every record every time? could you keep track of timestamp and only need to interact with records that have been created or updated since that timestamp? also you probably want to make sure this type of task doesn't overlap if it were to take longer than 1 minute to run

Comment: updateOrInsert won't work either. I get duplicate entry error:    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'wise' for key 'maintenance_machines_machine_name_unique' (SQL: insert into `maintenance_machines` (`machine_name`, `external_id`, `machine_status`, `created_at`) values (wise, 1, 1, 2020-08-13 09:12:54))

Comment: the error means it didn't find a matching record using the first array as where conditions so it will then insert

Comment: I suppose I can check for records created after I've run the job for the first time, if only I can find my way around the old project. Currently, there are no timestamps for the new records there, and the project is from someone who made it in its own custom made framework. Basically its hell :)

Comment: I think updateOrInsert Method worked. Thanks